# During transition of the electron from high to low energy state, is the photon released always of same energy?

Tags: photons, atomic-physics, photometry

Is it not possible that during transition of an electron from higher to lower energy state, it can release multiple photons of low energy instead of a single photon of the exact energy difference between the two states?

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible, and it's called (unsurprisingly) [two photon emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_absorption#Two-photon_emission).

However the probability of two or multi photon emission is generally lower than for single photon emission by several orders of magnitude, so it's hard to observe.